# Is it possible to automatically connect to Bluetooth LE device when it comes in range after pairing and and connected automatically to device?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to connect UA-651 bp smart to mobile phone.but i am not able to autoconnect my app with device when it is in range?
i also tried below code bt it didn't work for me .plz give me solution for it

```
if (device == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
            return false;
        }
        // We want to directly connect to the device, so we are setting the
        // autoConnect parameter to false.
        // boolean: Whether to directly connect to the remote device (false) or
        // to automatically connect as soon as the remote device becomes
        // available (true).
        mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, true, mGattCallback);
        Log.d(TAG, "Trying to create a new connection.");
        mBluetoothDeviceAddress = address;
        mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: when does you app reach the part of "`if(device==null)`"

Comment: if device is not found then it is in if(device==null)

Comment: so do you have a recursive call on false or what is the scan frequency

Comment: That piece of code should work. Please tell what does not work and what happens instead. How is the "device" variable set? As long as you know the bd address of a device you can create a BluetoothDevice object with that bd address and use that in your code you have above.

Comment: i want to connect bp monitor or weightscale to android phone automatically when it come into range.sometimes it get connected sometime not.got BLe status 19 and 133